# Data compilation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to organize raw data array using 1 formula so that the output is a table like in the sample to the right of the array? Criteria:

1. Unique team names from columns B and C for unique player names from column A.
2. Preference is given to those teams higher on the list

File link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HdEJSO3IBE46_HRQ6Bq5JE1nwTO-g2fbjYRnxs82A7Q/edit#gid=0

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(unique(tocol({A3:A;C3:C},1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,unique(torow(ifna(filter(E:F,(A:A=Σ)+(C:C=Σ))),1),1)}))
```

[image]